# pyqt qstatemachine graphical representation

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I am working on implementing a graphical representation of a state machine I already have. My question is, how can I generate a graphical representation using PyQT? so more clearly, I want a window to pop up with the fsm of the states and the transition shown.
Is this possible without manually drawing each state or building my own state drawing library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), this is a suite of graph layout tools and libraries and it used by many other programs for drawing graphs such as Doxygen and KCacheGrind.

You can use it either as a library, to link against; or write out a file, call the executable to process it and read the file back in. This second (file write/process/read) method is the most commonly used.

To do this you:

1. Write out the graph (your FSM) in dot format (a simple text format).
2. Call `dot` (one of the graphviz tools) with the output format as `dot`, this will append the layout information to the file
3. Read the dot file back in and use the position information

There are several libraries for doing this including for Python, see [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/).

Comment: well this is a little bit complicated. I am very new to all this. You know computer programmers are very lazy, this is why we are writing programs so that the machines do it for us.
Anyway, Isn't there an easier way to do the fsm visualization or at least an example on how to link the dot formatted text after being read to my code? Thanks again!

Comment: If you just want an image (not interactive), then dot can make [PNG](http://www.graphviz.org/content/output-formats#dpng) images and then you can just display that in a QLabel with [setPixmap](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop).

Comment: Thanks for your help, after some trial I managed to do it. Cheers!